# Solidity question about dynamic memory array

Tags: arrays, memory, storage, solidity

I read the docs about dynamic memory array, which use new uint to create and store the data in memory.
My question is where is the array store in follow case, storage or memory?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;
contract Storage {
    uint[] public array  = new uint[](3) ; 
}
```

In one hand, in solidity, the state variables, which are automatically assumed and can only be storage.
In the other hand, the dynamic memory array created by "new" is stored in memory according to the docs.
And this case confused me.

Answer (score 0):

In the example above, the array variable is a state variable of the Storage contract - on the blockchain's storage. However, the array itself is created dynamically in memory using the new keyword.

When the contract is deployed, the variable array is created on the blockchain's storage and set to an empty array. Then, the new uint creates a new array in memory with the specified length and assigns the memory array's reference to the storage variable array.

So the array is in memory when the contract is called and is executing; when the contract execution finishes, the state variables are saved to the blockchain storage.

Note: Storage is a finite resource, and state variables that use large amounts of storage can quickly run out of storage space, causing the contract to fail. While memory is only temporary, it is more scarce and expensive than storage. That is why it's important to be careful with dynamic arrays to avoid out-of-gas issues.

Comment: Helps a lot, thank you!

Comment: I think I need some knowledge about how the contract is called, and what makes the gas difference. These will definitely help me in writing contract codes.